# Using custom and built-in properties in Boost::Graph

Tags: c++, boost, properties, graph

I am building a graph class based on the following suggestion: [Modifying vertex properties in a Boost::Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671714/modifying-vertex-properties-in-a-boostgraph)

Unfortunately, I realized an unexpected behavior. When using my own vertex-properties (for simplicity please ignore the edge properties), the built-in properties seem not to be used.
So for example, when I have:

```
typedef adjacency_list<
        setS, // disallow parallel edges
        listS, // vertex container
        undirectedS, // undirected graph
        property<vertex_properties_t, VERTEXPROPERTIES>,
        property<edge_properties_t, EDGEPROPERTIES>
> GraphContainer;
```

I can retrieve my custom properties without any problem, but when I want to retrieve the vertex_index-property I always get the same value for each vertex, meaning a value of 0. The nodes are distinct, which is confirmed by num_vertices(MyGraph).
Then I thought that this might be due to missing the built-in properties, so I tried:

```
typedef adjacency_list<
        setS, // disallow parallel edges
        listS, // vertex container
        undirectedS, // undirected graph
        property<vertex_index_t, unsigned int , property< vertex_properties_t, VERTEXPROPERTIES> >,
        property<edge_properties_t, EDGEPROPERTIES>
> GraphContainer;
```

Again, when wanting to retrieve the index of whatever vertex, I get a value of 0.
Is this behavior normal? Does one have to set the built-in properties also, when using custom properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been a long time since I've used Boost.Graph, but Googling "vertex_index_t", [in hit #5 Andrew Sutton says](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2008/12/42998.php) :

> Just declaring a vertex index as a property (either bundled or interior, as 
>     here) won't buy you any new functionality. It just provides a place where 
>     you can assign an index for each vertex or edge. The problem that this 
>     half-solves is that nearly every algorithm in the distro requires a vertex 
>     index map (or edge index map, more rarely), and providing this will allow 
>     the default arguments to automatically extract a property map for 
>     vertices/edges.
>
> It won't - or shouldn't??? automatically assign indices. Also, if you remove 
>     a vertex or edge, you may have to renumber vertices.

So seems the idea is to standardize the concept across algorithms that want to *read* the numbers, but you still have to do the *writing* yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes I overlook the most trivial but useful search terms.
On top of this, I discovered the following default behavior, thanks to the answer of Vladimir Prus in http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/5794 and permalink: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.user/5797

Basically, when using vecS as storage for the vertices, the vertex_index - property is automatically active and the values are automatically set too.